# Implementation of a Provider in AngularJS with TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I try to implement a provider with TypeScript that has dependencies to services. I think I have to inject those services into the get function, but how is this done in TypeScript?

In JavaScript it is implemented like this:

```
angular.module('HTML5Shell.Services')
.provider('service', [
    'baseService',
    function (baseService) {

        return {
            $get: ['$rootScope',
                function ($rootScope) {

                    return {
                        method: function (param) {
                            return 'method called';
                        }
                    };
            }]
        };
    }]);
```

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution - maybe it is the desired solution to implement a provider, except using any ;-)

```
module services {
    'use strict';

export class Service {

        private $rootScope:any;

        public start($rootScope:any) {
            this.$rootScope = $rootScope;
        }

        public serviceMethod() {
            this.$rootScope ...
        }
}

export class ServiceProvider implements ng.IServiceProvider {

        static $inject = ['baseService'];

        constructor(private baseService:any) {
        }

        $get = ['$rootScope', ($rootScope:any) => {
                var translationService = new Service();
                translationService.start($rootScope);
                return translationService;
            }];

        public configure = () => {
            this.baseService.method();
        }
}

    angular
        .module('Module')
        .provider('service', ServiceProvider);
}
```

Comment: With that solution you get a new instance for every injection because of the new Service();